# How to efficiently get the Complement of a Domain and several Intervals (IntervalComplement?)

Tags: algorithm, intervals

Suppose you have a list of intervals (or tuples), such as:

```
intervals = {{3,7}, {17,43}, {64,70}};
```

And you wanted to know the intervals of all numbers not included above, e.g.:

```
myRange = 100;

numbersNotUed[myRange,intervales]

(*out: {{1,2},{8,16},{44,63},{71,100}}*)
```

What would be the most efficient way to approach this?

*Mathematica* currently supports `IntervalIntersection` but not `IntervalComplement`.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
int = {{3, 7}, {17, 43}, {64, 70}};

com = Partition[#, 2]& @ {1, Sequence @@ Riffle[int[[All, 1]] - 1, int[[All, 2]] + 1], 100}
```

> {{1, 2}, {8, 16}, {44, 63}, {71, 100}}

```
NumberLinePlot[{Interval @@ int, Interval @@ com}, PlotTheme -> "Detailed"]
```

[image]

Comment: I marked this as the answer because it works... but it is susceptible to bugs. For example, try `int = {{3, 7}, {7, 10}, {17, 43}, {64, 70}};` and then run
`com = Partition[#, 2] &@{1, Sequence @@ Riffle[int[[All, 1]] - 1, int[[All, 2]] + 1], 100}`. You'll get `{{1, 2}, {8, 6}, {11, 16}, {44, 63}, {71, 100}}` which is peculiar

Comment: `int = List @@ (IntervalUnion @@ Interval /@ int)` appears to fix this problem...

Answer (score 3):

```
f1 = Partition[Flatten[{0, Select[Flatten@#, Function[x, x < #2]], #2 + 1}], 
      2, 2, {1, -1}, {}, ({1, -1} + {##}) /. {1, 0} -> Nothing &]&;

f1[{{3, 7}, {17, 43}, {64, 70}}, 80]
```

> {{1, 2}, {8, 16}, {44, 63}, {71, 80}}

Also

```
f2 = BlockMap[({1, -1} + #) /. {1, 0} -> Nothing &, 
      Flatten[{0, Select[Flatten@#, Function[x, x < #2]], #2 + 1}], 2] &;
f2[{{3, 7}, {17, 43}, {64, 70}}, 80]
```

> {{1, 2}, {8, 16}, {44, 63}, {71, 80}}

**Note:** In versions before 10.2  you can use `` Developer`PartitionMap `` in place of [`BlockMap`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/BlockMap.html) above. (thanks: @CarlWoll)

Comment: Your implementation has a bug: please check `f1[{{1, 7}, {64, 80}}, 80]`.

Comment: Thank you @AlexeyPopkov.  Fixed now.

Comment: As of M10.2, you could use `BlockMap` instead of ``Developer`PartitionMap``.

Comment: Thank you @CarlWoll, I updated with a reference to `BlockMap`.

Comment: `f1[{{1, 7}}, 80]` still incorrectly returns `{{1, 0}, {8, 80}}`. The bug is only partially fixed.

Comment: @AlexeyPopkov, thank you again. Updated with a fix.

Answer (score 0):

Here is another implementation. It assumes that all the intervals lie in the specified range *and* intervals are sorted *and* aren't overlapping:

```
integerIntervalComplement[completeInterval : {start_, end_}, {subIntervals___}] := 
  If[First[#2] - Last[#1] <= 1, Nothing, {Last[#1] + 1, First[#2] - 1}] & @@@ 
   Partition[{{start - 1}, subIntervals, {end + 1}}, 2, 1];
```

Testing:

```
integerIntervalComplement[{1, 80}, {{3, 7}, {17, 43}, {64, 70}}]
```

> ```
> {{1, 2}, {8, 16}, {44, 63}, {71, 80}}
> ```

```
integerIntervalComplement[{1, 80}, {{1, 7}, {64, 80}}]
```

> ```
> {{8, 63}}
> ```

```
integerIntervalComplement[{1, 80}, {{2, 7}, {64, 79}}]
```

> ```
> {{1, 1}, {8, 63}, {80, 80}}
> ```

```
integerIntervalComplement[{1, 80}, {}]
```

> ```
> {{1, 80}}
> ```

If the intervals overlap, one can preprocess them first using `Interval`, for example:

```
List @@ Interval @@ {{30, 40}, {3, 7}, {8, 12}, {1, 10}}

{{1, 12}, {30, 40}}
```

This also removes the condition for subintervals to be sorted.